# How to install latest allure 1 release?

Tags: allure

How to install latest allure 1 version?

Since release of allure 2, references to allure 1 binaries were removed from all sources. It seem to be not possible to install allure 1 via HomeBrew.

Allure 2 is great, however some plugins are not yet compatible with it. It would be nice to have a convenient way to install allure 1 for a time being.

Comment: What plugins are not compatible with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Allure 1 releases from Github https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/releases/tag/allure-core-1.5.2